# Obtaining access to redux dispatch in a react container component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a container component called `ButtonContainer` which is passing two bits of state to the button presentational component. The problem is, the container needs to pass an onclick function which uses `dispatch` but I don't know how to get access to it. See the code below. How can I get access to dispatch?

### ButtonContainer.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fooAction , barAction } from '../foobarActions.js'
import ButtonComponent from './ButtonComponent.jsx'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  var buttonText = this.state.foo + this.state.bar
  var buttonOnClick = function(e, coord) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.nativeEvent.which === 1) { // left click
      dispatch(fooAction);
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.which === 3) {
      dispatch(barAction); // right click
    } else {
      console.log("Unknown click");
    }
  }
  return {
    buttonText: buttonText
    buttonOnClick: buttonOnClick
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {}
}

const ButtonContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ButtonComponent)

export default ButtonContainer;
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `buttonOnClick` with `mapDispatchToProps`? That's the preferred way to pass actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done in the `mapDispatchToProps` function, but you should leave the "which click" logic in the presentational component (`ButtonComponent`).

```
class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.nativeEvent.which === 1) { // left click
      this.props.leftClick();
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.which === 3) { // right click
      this.props.rightClick();
    } else {
      console.log("Unknown click");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    buttonText: this.state.foo + this.state.bar
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    leftClick: () => dispatch(fooAction),
    rightClick: () => dispatch(barAction)
  }
}

const ButtonContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ButtonComponent)

export default ButtonContainer;
```